# tablesorter, using 2 date range filter

Tags: reactjs, filter, tablesorter

I want to use 2 date range filters, so I had used this options:

```
.tablesorter({
    widgets: ['filter'],
    widgetOptions: {
    ,'','ts_cf_datepicker','ts_cf_datepicker', 'ts_cf_select_single']
    }
})
```

So, I have 5 columns:
the first one doesnt have a filter.

The 2nd have a a normal input search filter

**3rd and 4th** has a ts_cf_datepicker and here's my problem.

5th has a ts_cf_select_single filter.

When I use the date picker on the 3rd or 4th column filter, both columns are filled with the same data. How can I fix that problem? This is my table (I'm using React.js)

```
<table ref="listaElementos" className="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-align-vertical uk-table-nowrap tablesorter tablesorter-altair" id="ts_custom_filters">{/* id="ts_custom_filters ts_pager_filter" */}
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th className="uk-text-center filter-false remove">ID</th>
        <th className="uk-text-center" data-placeholder="Buscar empresa">Empresa</th> 
        <th className="uk-text-center" data-placeholder="Seleccione rango">Fecha</th>
        <th className="uk-text-center" data-placeholder="Seleccione rango">Vencimiento</th>
        <th className="uk-text-center filter-select" data-placeholder="Seleccione Vigencia">Vigencia</th>
        <th className="uk-text-center filter-false remove">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {contratos}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't (or I don't know how) use id with those inputs filters separately, because Tablesorter build those inputs don't know how.
Help please.

Comment: Try the [`filter_selectSource` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource).. The javascript provided appears to be incomplete, but it would make it easier to help if you provided rendered HTML, or better yet a jsFiddle showing the problem.

Comment: This is the rendered parts of the html (table and modal) https://jsfiddle.net/9b0t2erg/1/ (just the html and React.js code, it needs more js and css but I'm just giving you my code to render it)

Comment: Well, I solved it. I just made 2 modals, one for each column id.